# How to remove all event listeners made from a specific loaded file?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

```
<div id="loaded-content">
    @Scripts.Render("~/someScript.js")
</div>
```

this appears to be equivalent to

```
<div id="loaded-content">
    <script src="/someScript.js"></script>
</div>
```

When the above content is loaded with ajax every event listener from `someScript.js` becomes active and remains, even if the content is later removed via jQuery like so:

```
$("#loaded-content").remove();
```

What should be done to prevent the same event listeners from being activated multiple times if the content is constantly loaded and removed? I tried adding a global variable `var scriptHasRun = false;`, then the following code in `someScript.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(scriptHasRun){
        return;
    }
    scriptHasRun = true;

    <more code>

});
```

It works for `someScript.js`, but then came `someOtherScript.js` that appears to be loaded the same way, so to prevent things in advance I used the same method with another variable `var otherScriptHasRun = false;` and the second time it gets loaded in the page it no longer works. It started working normally when I removed the check. I'd like to know how to replicate the circumstances of `someOtherScript.js`, or in case that's normal, what could be causing `someScript.js` to be loaded multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery. I'm not sure what you have in someScript.js, but you can use

```
$('#element').off('click', handleClick);
```

to unbind event from element before attaching it so it does not get attached multiple times.

other option I would try to use is to ad specific event related classes to element to mark them as already having the event attached and use something like the line below to attache the events so you can skip using variable scriptHasRun to check if script has been loaded.

```
$('#myElemetSelector:not(.boundToEventX)').addClass('boundToEventX').on('click',  onElemetClickedFunction);
```

Comment: That's for unbinding each individual element. In the case of `someOtherScript.js` everything unbinds itself when I remove the html that called it.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because the event listeners in `someScript.js` are bound to the body and the ones in `someOtherScript.js` are bound to the elements themselves, so the code that checks if the script has been run before isn't needed on them, but still is for `someScript.js`.